# Using custom ports with Cloudflare

Tags: ajax, http, https, dns, cloudflare

I have a server running on `my.ip.ad.re.ss:2086` and I read that the port 2086 was supported in [this article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-). I have tried to use Cloudflare DNS to forward `sub.mydomain.com` to this server, but when I go to `sub.mydomain.com:2086` I get redirected to `https://sub.mydomain.com` and an error page with HTTP 523 is shown.

I know I can choose "DNS only" but it is important to me that the server is accessible over HTTPS (not because sensitive data is transferred but because of browser rules for doing AJAX calls from a HTTPS page).

How do I make this work?

Comment: are you using CNAME or SRV records?

Comment: I am using A records

Comment: According to the article you mentioned, suppose my server 80 port is reserved by another service, so I run the desired service on port 8080 and what should I do in Cloudflare DNS record then? How can tell Cloudflare route the given domain name to the VPS IP with the 8080 port?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari-aGn If I remember correctly, you set up DNS in the usual way, and then you have to use http://your-domain.com:8080 as the URL when accessing your service.

Comment: @tjespe Hmm, That being said, I cannot connect a domain.com to a service on port 8080 without entering the respective port at the end of the domain. or maybe I could do that by running an Nginx. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved when I changed to 2087. This is because Cloudflare treats 2086 as a http port, and 2087 as a https port.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that we can really troubleshoot here.  Please contact supportATcloudflareDOTcom so that a support engineer can dig in on this issue.